# Flutter receive share intent text as Stream

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent

I'm testing some functions with flutter to try to find out if I'm able to handle it and right now it doesn't seem that I would be able to make it.

I've set up a app which should be able to handle incoming text from android intents. With that text I've wanted to open a specific screen of my app and load specific data into the screen.

I've tried so many different approaches that I can't even remember when it worked best and what went wrong.

Right now I have the following code.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:label="My cool App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyFlutterActivity"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

`MyApplication.kt`

```
    class MyApplication : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    lateinit var flutterEngine: FlutterEngine

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Instantiate a FlutterEngine.
        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)

        // Start executing Dart code to pre-warm the FlutterEngine.
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        )

        // Cache the FlutterEngine to be used by FlutterActivity.
        FlutterEngineCache
            .getInstance()
            .put("my_engine_id", flutterEngine)
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)

    }
```

As you can see I'm also using the FlutterFirebaseMessagingService to receive notifications, which I'm right now not already sure if it is still working as it already was.

`FlutterActivity.kt`

```
class MyFlutterActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private var sharedText: String? = null

    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? {
        return FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("my_engine_id")
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
      // Use the GeneratedPluginRegistrant to add every plugin that's in the pubspec.
      //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
      handleShareIntent()
      MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), "com.example.app.shared.data")
        .setMethodCallHandler {call: MethodCall , result: MethodChannel.Result ->
          if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
            result.success(sharedText)
            sharedText = null
          }
        }
    }

  fun handleShareIntent() {
    //val intent = getIntent()
    val action = intent.action
    val type = intent.type
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
      if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent)
      }
    }
  }

  fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
  }

}
```

`main.dart`

```
  static const platform =
      const MethodChannel('com.example.app.shared.data');

  static Stream<String> get sharedData {
    return new Stream<String>.fromFuture(
        platform.invokeMethod("getSharedText"));
  }

//... inside build
        StreamProvider<String>.value(
          lazy: true,
          value: sharedData,
        ),

// .. handle inside build
    final String sharedData = Provider.of<String>(context);

// .. handle shared Data and open Screen..
```

I've tried to log every step to find out what's not working.
So I connected my android phone and tried to debug, but didn't found a step where to handle the incoming data, even if the text is successfully handled inside the "handleSendText" method of the FlutterAcitivity.kt.
What even more confused me is, that if i save a dart file / press hot reload, my breakpoint inside the sharedData getter of the main.dart is getting called and from there everything works as it should.

But why do I have to hot reload where it should start itself instead.
Am I'm missing anything or doing wrong at this point?

Any help appreciated.